# Sensu Windows check configuration

Tags: rubygems, sensu

I am following instructions on the [Sensu page](http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.16/adding_a_check), under "Windows" section. I get following error:

```
PS C:\Tools\sensu\embedded\bin> gem install sensu-plugin --no-rdoc --no-ri
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sensu-plugin' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect 
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your install of rubygems is either missing a CA cert in the SSL chain, or it's mismatched with the SSL certificate chain on rubygems.org.

As a **workaround** you can specify the **non-secure** rubygems.org as the source:

```
gem install sensu-plugin --source=http://rubygems.org
```

However, the **better** and more permanent solution is to correct the SSL certification chain error.

First, ensure your openSSL is up to date with the latest version (1.0.1k, I believe is the current version).

Then update rubygems:

```
gem update --system
```

Then install gems as normal, for example

```
gem install sensu-plugin
```

Comment: I had similar issue on my Linux machine and solved it by installing ruby-dev and other packages. I will try it on Windows and will get back to this QA. Thanks for your suggestion.